# Reshape array using numpy - ValueError: cannot reshape array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have an array of floats `vec` which I want to reshape

```
vec.shape
>>> (3,)
len(vec[0]) # all 3 rows of vec have 150 columns
>>> 150
np.reshape(vec, (3,150))
>>> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3 into shape (3,150)
```

but I get the error above.

What's going wrong? How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: `np.concatenate(vec).reshape(3,150)`?

Comment: `vec.dtype` yields `dtype('O')`

Comment: what is `type(vec[0])` ?

Comment: @B.M.  `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: @Divakar I get the error `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions` if I try `np.concatenate` - which is strange because I have inspected all my vectors and they all have 150 elements of type `dtype=float32`

Comment: Maybe its nested one more level, so try : `np.concatenate([np.concatenate(i) for i in vec])`.

Comment: `np.concatenate` without axis parameter should join any combination of 1d arrays - into one long one.  The error means that there's a mix in the number of dimensions of the arrays.  Most likely one is 2d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `vec.shape` means that the array has 3 items.  But they are dtype object, that is, pointers to items else where in memory.

Apparently the items are arrays themselves.  One of the `concatenate` or `stack` functions can join them into one array, provided the dimensions match.

I'd suggest printing

```
[x.shape for x in vec]
```

to verify the shape.  And of course make sure that those sub arrays are not, themselves object dtypes.

---

```
In [261]: vec = np.empty(3, object)
In [262]: vec[:] = [np.arange(10), np.ones(10), np.zeros(10)]
In [263]: vec
Out[263]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
       array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]),
       array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])], dtype=object)
In [264]: vec.reshape(3,10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-264-cd555975140c> in <module>()
----> 1 vec.reshape(3,10)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3 into shape (3,10)
In [265]: [x.shape for x in vec]
Out[265]: [(10,), (10,), (10,)]
In [266]: np.stack(vec)
Out[266]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
In [267]: np.concatenate(vec)
Out[267]: 
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
In [268]: np.concatenate(vec).reshape(3,10)
Out[268]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

---

`len` is not a good test; use `shape`.  For example if I change one array to be 2d

```
In [269]: vec[1]=np.ones((10,1))
In [270]: vec
Out[270]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
       array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]]),
       array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])], dtype=object)
In [271]: [len(x) for x in vec]
Out[271]: [10, 10, 10]
In [272]: [x.shape for x in vec]
Out[272]: [(10,), (10, 1), (10,)]
In [273]: np.concatenate(vec)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-273-a253d8b9b25d> in <module>()
----> 1 np.concatenate(vec)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```